# Showing something is well-defined

Tags: abstract-algebra

In order to show something is well-defined, define some mapping  $f:x\rightarrow X$. So in order to show this is well-defined assume $a=b$. then show $f(a)=f(b)$ right?

So now for something a little more complicated. Let $A=\{N(H), g_1N(H),...g_nN(H)\}$ be the set of left cosets for $N(H)$ in $G$, where $N(H)$ is the normalizer of $H$ in $G$. and let $C=\{gHg^-1|g\in G\}$ be the collection of conjugates of H. Now let $\phi$ be the mapping from $A \rightarrow C$. Show it is well-defined. Assume $xN(H)=gN(H)$. How do I show this part? the mapping $\phi$ is $\phi (gN(H))=gHg^{-1}$.

Also where how would I show it is 1-1 and onto? Then how does that prove that [G:N(H)] is the number of conjugates of H in G?

For the 1-1 part am I trying to show that $g_1=g_2$ or $g_1N(H)=g_2N(H)$?

Comment: Can you describe $\phi$?

Comment: I always forget that you know. I added it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you assume $xN(H) = gN(H)$, and you want to show $\phi(xN(H)) = \phi(gN(H))$.  That is, you need to show that $xHx^{-1} = gHg^{-1}$.

Hint: $xN(H) = gN(H)$ may be rewritten as $g^{-1}x N(H) = N(H)$, which is equivalent to $g^{-1}x \in N(H)$.  Does this help you prove the desired result?

Comment: so since $g^{-1}x \in N(H)$, then $g^{-1}x=gHg^{-1}=H$

Comment: No, that's not correct: $g^{-1}x$ is an element of the group $G$, while $gHg^{-1}$ is a set of elements of $G$.  You'll need to use the definition of $N(H)$ somehow...

Comment: definiton of N(H) is $gH=Hg$

Comment: That's a little imprecise, but more importantly: you'll confuse yourself if you use $g$ in two different ways.  You already fixed an element $g$, and $g$ was *NOT* assumed to be an element of $N(H)$.  So far the only element of $N(H)$ that we know of is $g^{-1}x$.

Comment: okay so then $g^{-1}x$=kHk^{-1} for all k in G?

Comment: What do you think $kHk^{-1}$ means?

Comment: that H is normal if it equals H. or kH=Hk

Comment: Let me put it another way.  $kHk^{-1} = $ what?

Comment: $g^{-1}x$? I dont know.

Comment: Definitely not; you're confusing an element of a group with a whole *set* of elements of a group (see my previous comments).  I recommend that you go back and think about this some more.  Specifically, you need to figure out what is meant by expressions like $kH$ (when $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $k$ is an element of $G$).  That's a different question than the one you asked, but until you figure this out, I don't think you will be able to figure out your question about $N(H)$, etc.  Once you understand the notation, then I think my answer will make more sense to you.  Good luck!